# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to fix below error:

`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'`

but still getting following error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.obtainApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;`

Below is my setup:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

                <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"/>
                <import resource="classpath:IOC.xml"/>

        </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
          <display-name>Bai Tap</display-name>        
          <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**IOC.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">



    <bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BaiTap" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>  

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="edao" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public Employee(int id, String name, float salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public int saveEmployee(Employee e) {
        String query = "insert into employee(id,name,salary) values(" + e.getId() +"," + e.getName() + "," + e.getSalary() +")";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }

    public int updateEmployee(Employee e) {
        String query = "update employee set name = "+e.getName()+",salary="+e.getSalary()+"where id="+e.getId()+"";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }

    public int deleteEmployee(Employee e) {
        String query = "delete from employee where id = "+e.getId()+"";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Test {

       @RequestMapping("/")
       @ResponseBody
       public static void main(String[] args) {

          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("IOC.xml");
          EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("edao");
          int status = dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",3500));
          System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

> porm.xml  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>           4.0.0
>           com.javatpoint
>           BaiTap
>           0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>           war

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code

```
@Controller
public class Test {

       @RequestMapping("/")
       @ResponseBody
       public static void main(String[] args) {    
          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("IOC.xml");
          EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("edao");
          int status = dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",3500));
          System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

return type is `void`, it means the method return nothing. Therefore, it cannot return `@ResponseBody` in same time.

`main` method is reserved for entry point of Java Class, you must change method's name.

Comment: i deleted @ResponseBody but still error and 
I will also try to improve method naming

Answer (score 0):

How have you constructed your project?

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means that this method does not exist at runtime. 
This method would have been invoked from inside a library but it was unable to find that method.

If it is a non Spring Boot project, can you please check if you have included `spring-core` and `spring-context` in your setup.

Comment: I have added a file "porm.xml" you can review to help me

Answer (score 0):

As you have applicationContext.xml which imports IOC.xml you should change your

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("IOC.xml");
```

to

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

**EDIT**

You need to restructure your controller class also

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("IOC.xml");
          EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("edao");
          int status = dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",3500));
          System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

And finally run your this class.

Comment: I have changed but it still fails